# gather() with two key columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset that has two rows of data, and want to tidy them using something like gather() but don't know how to mark both as key columns.

The data looks like:

```
Country  US   Canada  US 
org_id   332  778     920
02-15-20 25   35      54
03-15-20 30   10      60
```

And I want it to look like

```
country  org_id  date      purchase_price 
US       332      02-15-20 25
Canada   778      02-15-20 35
US       920      02-15-20 54
US       332      03-15-20 30
Canada   778      03-15-20 10
US       920      03-15-20 60
```

I know gather() can move the country row to a column, for example, but is there a way to move both the country and org_id rows to columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to have duplicate column names in the data so I'll rename one of them.

```
names(df)[4] <- 'US_1'
```

- `gather` has been retired and replaced with `pivot_longer`.
- This is not a traditional reshape because the data in the 1st row needs to be treated differently than rest of the rows so we can perform the reshaping separately and combine the result to get one final dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% slice(-1L) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Country)

df %>% 
  slice(1L) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Country, values_to = 'org_id') %>%
  select(-Country) %>%
  inner_join(df1, by = 'name') %>%
  rename(Country = name, date = Country) -> result

result

#  Country org_id date     value
#  <chr>    <int> <chr>    <int>
#1 US         332 02-15-20    25
#2 US         332 03-15-20    30
#3 Canada     778 02-15-20    35
#4 Canada     778 03-15-20    10
#5 US_1       920 02-15-20    54
#6 US_1       920 03-15-20    60
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("org_id", "02-15-20", "03-15-20"), 
    US = c(332L, 25L, 30L), Canada = c(778L, 35L, 10L), US = c(920L, 
    54L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we paste together `Country` and `org_id`

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- set_names(data, paste(names(data), data[1,], sep = "-")) 
data
  Country-org_id US-332 Canada-778 US-920
1         org_id    332        778    920
2       02-15-20     25         35     54
3       03-15-20     30         10     60
```

Then, we drop the first row, pivot the table and separate the column name.

```
df <-  data %>% 
    slice(2:n()) %>% 
    rename(date = `Country-org_id`) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -date, values_to = "price") %>% 
    separate(col = name, into = c("country", "org_id"), sep = "-")

df

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  date     country org_id price
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  <int>
1 02-15-20 US      332       25
2 02-15-20 Canada  778       35
3 02-15-20 US      920       54
4 03-15-20 US      332       30
5 03-15-20 Canada  778       10
6 03-15-20 US      920       60
```